# How to deploy a flexipage with it activated as the Org Default?

Tags: deployment, flexipages

When I have deployed via the Metadata API a flexipage that is the Org Default in the sandbox it does not get assigned as the Org Default in the target org. Is it possible to deploy the Org Default setting for the flexipage?

Comment: Are you deploying the object as well?

Comment: I can confirm that the metadata is located in the .object file if the flexipage is activated as org default.